# iOS Shortcuts not registering some presses

Tags: iphone, ios, bug, shortcuts-app

Whenever I try to enter settings for some actions, the variable menu won’t show up. It will lift up as if I’m trying to move the action even though my finger is on the variable. This is currently happening with the “filter files” action, and I can’t click on the ‘sort by’ variables. I have tried restarting my phone, no dice. What’s going on? (iOS 15)

Comment: Shortcuts on iOS 15 is buggy - I'm not putting this as an answer cause it's not helpful, but it *is* the answer

Comment: @Ezekiel That’s what I was afraid of. Is there anything I can try to fix it?

Comment: iOS 15.1 was released today and may fix shortcuts issues